# Overload Resolution Ambiguity

Tags: kotlin

After upgrading to Kotlin 1.7.0 i start to receive this error:

> Overload resolution ambiguity:
> public final fun remove(p0:Property!): Boolean defined in
> net.fortuna.ical4j.model.PropertyList
>
> public open fun remove(element: Property!): Boolean defined in
> net.fortuna.ical4j.model.PropertyList

In this piece of code

```
if (it.properties.getProperty<DtEnd>("DTEND") != null) {
      it.properties.remove(it.properties.getProperty<DtEnd>("DTEND"))
}
```

How can i disambiguate this?

Comment: Is there any chance you have two versions of the net.fortuna.ical4 library on your classpath? Somebody correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think it is possible for this library to define both those methods in the same class.

Comment: I think its not possible. If i revert the upgrade to kotlin 1.7.0 from 1.6.10 the error is gone. But how can i check if i have two versions of the net.fortuna.ical4 in my classpath?

Comment: You can use [this method](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-print-out-the-current-project-classpath/) to print all jars that are currently on your classpath

Comment: The problem is suddenly resolved. I dont know how or why